# How to make an inline landscape 2 column page look the same as a separate one from pdf?

Tags: listings, landscape

I have a document I would like to add a code listing to. The document format is as shown:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

this is a large project with lots of sections, one I would like to add is a precise code listing. I created a code listing like so:

```
\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\lstset{%
numbers=left}}

\lstinputlisting[label=preface, caption=directories,basicstyle=\small,breaklines=true]{directory_listing.txt}

\end{document}
```

now I can add this to the document by using:

```
\begin{landscape}
\includepdf[pages={1-3}, angle=90]{code_listing/code_listing.pdf}
\end{landscape}
```

but so that I can link to the content within the code listing I would like to do something like:

```
\begin{landscape}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\lstset{%
numbers=left}

\lstinputlisting[label=preface, caption=directories,basicstyle=\small,,breaklines=true]{code_listing/directory_listing.txt}

\end{multicols}
\end{landscape}
```

within my document.

Unfortunately when I try this the lines are a lot shorter and this leads to some horrible wrapping. 
how can you make both of these code snippets look the same?

Comment: This is an old question, but if you still want an answer, you should edit your question to add the contents of your `directory_listing.txt` so other people can reproduce the problem at home.